# SQLite if there is existing data skip or overwrite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have some x,y coordinates in my sqlite but when I add a new data I want to check the data and if there is same data overwrite or skip it. Coordinates come automatically from another method.

```
public void DBCreate(){
   SQLITEDATABASE = openOrCreateDatabase("LatLongDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, mCurrentLocationLAT VARCHAR,mCurrentLocationLONG VARCHAR);");
}

public void SubmitData2SQLiteDB(){


    SQLiteQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (mCurrentLocationLAT, mCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES('"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"');";
    SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(SQLiteQuery);

    Toast.makeText(CampaignActivity.this,"OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lined up the code like this one created a new table, but it always overwrites now.

```
 public void DBCreate(){
    SQLITEDATABASE = openOrCreateDatabase("LatLongDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable43(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FAVCurrentLocationLAT VARCHAR,FAVCurrentLocationLONG VARCHAR);");
}
public void SubmitData2SQLiteDB(){
    SQLiteQuery = "INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO myTable43(id, FAVCurrentLocationLAT, FAVCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES(1, '"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"');";
        SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(SQLiteQuery);
        Toast.makeText(CampaignActivity.this,"OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the table has a primary key then use INSERT OR REPLACE,

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable (id, mCurrentLocationLAT, mCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES(1, :lat, :long)
```

and if the table doesn't have a primary key then fix that.

Comment: Thank you sir. Code is just this, do you know where I can find a document about adding primary key.

Comment: @H.P. this is usually done during table creation, and SQLite's "ALTER TABLE" support is very limited. you can work around it by creating a new temporary table and copying over all your current data, then DROP'ing the original table (this will also delete everything in the original table, which is why the backup is required), then create the original table again with a primary key, then copying all the data back from the temporary table then delete the temporary table, but it's messy :P it's best just to create the primary key together with the table.. what does you table look like now?

Comment: @hanshernik Thank you for your response :) For now my data is for just testing I can create a new table it is not a problem. I just started working with SQLite nowadays.

Comment: @H.P. oh ok then. DROP the table and just re-create it with the id then, it should look something like ```DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myTable`; CREATE TABLE `myTable` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `mCurrentLocationLAT` REAL, `mCurrentLocationLONG` REAL);``` and REAL is the native SQLite floating-point-type (it has others with higher precision, but REAL is the highest-performance one, and should have more than enough precision for longtitude/latitude on planet earth)

Comment: Adding a unique index on the coordinates works just as well. (Or use them as a composite primary key)

Comment: @hanshenrik, I tried your code but now it always overwrites :(

Comment: @H.P. running that code is a 1-time operation to fix your original table, you're only supposed to run that code once during installation, and never again.

Comment: @Shawn I have the primary key but it overwrites or writes the same data again

Comment: @H.P. if you want to insert new data without overwriting any old data then insert it with NULL as the id, or don't specify the id at all, and SQLite will create the new primary key for you and insert it next to your old data, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Sir no, I want to add data, but if there is same data skip or overwrite.

Comment: @H.P. to add new data: `INSERT INTO myTable (id, mCurrentLocationLAT, mCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES(NULL, 1.3, 3.7);` - with NULL as the id, the new data will be appended.

Comment: @hanshenrik Sir thank you for your response but output is same :( , 

 `SQLiteQuery = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable72(id, FAVCurrentLocationLAT, FAVCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES(NULL,'"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"');"; `

Tried this one but does not work :(